# How to select the number of outputs of a nueral networks

Tags: theano, lasagne

I have a classification problem of characters. I have converted the charcters to ASCI values. How to select the number of outputs of a nueral network. Does it depend on the max vlaues of the yTrain.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is, I try to answer it.
The number of outputs of a nueral network is 26
if you want to classify a,b,c..z, letter from a handwriting picture,
you can let your neuron network outputs  being a 26 length of vector.
and only 1 element will have value 1 ,others are 0 in the vector for one input.
the element of value 1 means correct letter for the input.
for example if the correct letter is 'c', the vector can be [0,0,1,0....]

more deeplearning info http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/contents.html